# if statement not working keeps firing a function

Tags: php, sql

I have a problem with my script im using. the if $addcount is not working. it continues to fire the insertMessage function when i dont want it to. Any ideas why?

```
if(($result->data != '') && ($result->data != null)) {
    $wallCount = 0;
    $addCount = 0;
    foreach($result->data as $thread){
        $wallCount++;
        $fromId = $thread->from->id;
        $message = $thread;
        if($fromId == $user['Id']){
            if($addCount < 100) {
                insertMessage($user['Id'], $message, $user['Num']);
                $addCount++;
                sleep(1);
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: print addCount in your loop and you will see the problem

Comment: I think we need more information, like how big is the $result->data array? and what is it exactly that your trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your script, it will call insertMessage 100 times (0-99).  Before the if statement, echo the counter to see what it is doing:

```
...
echo $addCount."<br />";
if($addCount < 100) {
...
```

Comment: There's no doubt that $addCount is being incremented, he has another problem.

Comment: Yes exactly.  He says its not working, so perhaps it is being reset somewhere.  Maybe insertMessage has something that resets it.

Comment: My webhost was caching my files. It works correctly but sent me on a wild chace to figure out somthing that was working. Im sorry guys. Thanks for your help It was working right but